# how do i animate a flag with armatures

Tags: modeling, animation, armature

[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/kuiaLeupeG4)

okay...so...how do i animate a flag/item without attaching armatures to main body armature set?

the image attached has a blue bandana and big triangular side engines that articulate somewhat however i dont know how to do that.

i hope the video attached helps. [image]

Comment: it depends how you want the bandana to move, you can use Cloth simulation, or fake it with addons like Wiggle Bones or BoneDynamics (that make bones move as if there were physics). Also what you show ARE bones, as I said you can switch to the default octahedral appearance, but it won't help to animate in Blender because this setup is made for game engines

Comment: imaware that the setup in the video is made for game engines...fully aware...i dont need it to move much.

Comment: if you don't plan to export to a game engine, Cloth would be a good way to animate, just add a wind

Comment: im not planning on animating it...i just want to move it around...right now it is stiff as a board

Comment: you said "how do i animate a flag", so maybe clarify what you want   ;)   if you just want to change its shape, if it is correctly rigged, move the bones?

Comment: there are no bones on it same with the side skirts the only thing thats got bones is the main body